Serve folder with elysiajs in bun?
I want to serve a folder with elysiajs, kinda like in express where you use express.static().
I tried doing it like this:
import { Elysia } from 'elysia';
import { staticPlugin } from '@elysiajs/static';

const app = new Elysia()
.use(staticPlugin())
.get("/", Bun.file("public"))
.listen(3000);

console.log(
  ` Elysia is running at ${app.server?.hostname}:${app.server?.port}`
);

but i get an error saying: Directories can't be read like files.
Please help, i already tried doing everything i could imagine but i just cant get it working.

I think you don't need the:
.get("/", Bun.file("public"))
The staticPlugin already serve the /public folder by default, so deleting the line should be enough. If you want another folder you could change it like:
.use(staticPlugin('another-folder'))

The syntax for:
.get('/file', () => Bun.file("public"))

Is used only to serve single files.
Elysia doc

I think Elysiajs doesn't have a plugin that serves folders, but you can see an example of making a bun file server in this repository or use the http-server from nodejs
